# Kivy - Contents of window do not update while resizing

Tags: python, user-interface, resize, kivy, sdl-2

While resizing a `Kivy` window (by dragging the arrows at the edge of the screen), the contents of the window do not update while the window resizes and instead only update after I release the mouse button. For example, if I have a `Label` widget centered in the window and I resize the window, the label will stay in its position and will not re-center until I release the mouse button. How do I allow the contents of the window to update while it is resizing? I am running `Python 2.7.12` on `Windows 10`using `Kivy 1.9.1` with `SDL2` as the window provider.

Comment: If your Kivy is up to date, I'm not sure there's anything you can do to change this behaviour. It may be just a consequence of how the opengl context is resized on windows. Kivy master does have (or nearly have) some new options that might change this, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I think it behaves correctly on every other platform except Windows, but this should be pure SDL2 issue iirc, because I've seen openGL programs (bare, just some 3D objects) resizing in real-time and not just waiting for some event and if it works on other platforms (worked for me on Ubuntu), then it excludes Kivy as the cause of the issue as the Window implementation is the same i.e. creating an SDL2/openGL window.